# I want to migrate specific data of one table to another specific column which is in another database in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I just use the following query but it shows error. Any suggestions?

```
INSERT INTO test1.`tbl_news`.`file` 
SELECT * FROM test2.`tbl_download_media`.`media` 
WHERE TYPE = 'event'
```

Here I want to copy data from table `tbl_download_media` which have column `media` and type `event` of DB test2 to DB 'test1' having table `tbl_news` with column `file`

Here is the error:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '.file select * from
>   nic_data.tbl_download_media.media where type = 'event' at line 1

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: sorry i forgot to put this into it.here whats it says

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`file` 
select * from test2.`tbl_download_media`.`media` where type = 'event' at line 1 @ErayBalkanli

Comment: Try with this one instead: INSERT INTO test1.tbl_news(`file`) 
    SELECT media FROM test2.tbl_download_media
    WHERE TYPE = 'event'

Comment: @Hackerman has the correct answer, but aare you sure this is what you want to do? All other fields besides "file" will remain empty (this may still throw errors if some of the fields are not allowed to be null)

Comment: @JakubJudas ya im sorry i got my logic wrong actually i wanted to update my data on structure 'field' which has same id as on structure 'media'  Hackerman code worked but not what i wanted

Comment: @Hackerman thank you it worked but actually i wanted to update the data of column file with column media as they had same id. stupid of me it inserted new row. Sorry for not being clear do you have solution for this??

Comment: @JenishMaharjan In that case, try something like UPDATE test1.tbl_news n JOIN test2.tbl_download_media m ON n.id=m.id SET n.file=m.media;

Comment: @JakubJudas thank you so much man it worked. You're a life saviour :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `insert` statement has some minor `syntaxis` errors. This is the corrected version:

```
INSERT INTO test1.tbl_news(`file`) 
SELECT media FROM test2.tbl_download_media
WHERE TYPE = 'event'
```

Now, if you want to update based on same `id` for `event` type:

```
UPDATE test1.tbl_news AS b
INNER JOIN test2.tbl_download_media AS g 
ON (b.id = g.id)
SET b.file = g.media 
WHERE TYPE = 'event'
```